# VBA: Copy Hyperlink to Clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a hyperlink to clipboard by clicking in it.

At this moment I'm trying this code:

```
Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
clipboard.SetText Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Address
clipboard.PutInClipboard

End Sub
```

And the Microsoft Forms 2.0 object library it's already activate:

[image]

But this is not working, my clipboard continue empty.

I also tried this code

```
Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject, LinkURL As String
LinkURL = ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
With DataObj
    .SetText LinkURL
    .PutInClipboard
    .GetFromClipboard
    MsgBox .GetText
End With
End Sub
```

But unsuccessful again, I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: What is `Selection` when you run this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.hyperlinks

Comment: Ummm - that is the Microsoft Word documentation (you tagged the question with Excel). What do you have selected when you try to run this?

Comment: this is vba documentation, isn't it? i'm trying to copy ah hyperlink (in excel) to clipboard just clicking in it

Comment: [`Range.Hyperlinks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.hyperlinks) is the Excel documentation.... but what is `Selection`? Presumably a `Range`, but please give us more detail. What do you have selected? A cell?

Comment: the active cell which has a hyperlink

Comment: What does `Debug.Print Selection.Hyperlinks.Count` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this using this code:

```
Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    Application.GoTo Reference:=Target.Range
    Call CopyHyperlinkToClipboard(Target)
End Sub


Sub CopyHyperlinkToClipboard(Target)

    Dim MyData As New DataObject

    Row = Target.Range.Row
    Column = Target.Range.Column
    Chtoc = Cells(Row, Column).Value
    MyData.SetText Chtoc
    MyData.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Comment: If this answers the question press the green check mark to the left. This closes the question and gives you points!